# Is using a state-of-being in passive form feasible?

Tags: grammar

For example if I wanted to express "Alice , who was (once) not interesting, is being liked by everyone". Then what sort of grammar should I use?

> 面白くなかったアリスは、皆に好きであられる。

Is state of being in passive form possible? If yes, are there any other way to express it? Is this sentence gramatically correct and does it correctly express the intended meaning? What are the correct/other ways to convey my intended meaning(polite/informal)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Is state of being in passive form possible?"

Yes, it is, but **not** in the way that you seem to be thinking.  It is possible (and correct) mostly as "**suffering passive**".  For instance, you could say:

> 「アタシはあなたには興味{きょうみ}ないの。だから、いつまでも好{す}きで**いられて**も困{こま}るの。」

= "I am not interested in you and that is why it puts me in an awkward situation if (**I continue to be liked by you / you keep liking me**) for so long."

> 「そこまで政治{せいじ}に無関心{むかんしん}で**あられて**もねえ・・」 ← The entire main clause is left unsaid.

= "If you are indifferent toward politics to *that* degree, (it is troublesome)."

Your sentence:

> 「面白{おもしろ}くなかったアリスは、皆{みな}に好{す}きであられる。」

makes little sense, I am afraid to say, because of the last half of it.  Alice is happy that she is being liked, right?  If so, that is not suffering passive.

You could say 「みんなに**好かれている**」 to make it correct and natural.  Change 「いる」 to 「います」 to make it politer.

Answer (score 1):

The example sentence itself is wrong (correctly it should be アリスは、かつては面白くなかったが皆に好かれている). However, passive voice of predicates that stand for state of being per se is possible. e.g. アリスに人気者でいられては困る (it'd be unfavorable for me that Alice remains a popular person). That said, you won't see ある conjugated into passive in practice. If you find あられる, you would safely assume it's honorific.